# Time Evolution Operator Explained in The Theoretical Minimum: Quantum Mechanics book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution

In section 4.4 and 4.5 of "The Theoretical Minimum: Quantum Mechanics" book, there are a explanation about time evolution operator U(t).

The author explains that:

$U^\dagger (t)U(t) = I$

In sequence, he suposes the idea of an incremental change in time and says:

$U^\dagger (\epsilon )U(\epsilon) = I$

First, he consider the case where $\epsilon$ is zero and says that it should be obvious that
in this case the time-evolution operator is merely the unit operator I.

So, he does the folowing aprroximation:

$U(\epsilon) = I - i \epsilon H$

He uses this approximation to introduce the quantum Hamiltonian later in the book.

My doubt is that, I accepted the argument for  $U^\dagger (t)U(t) = I$, but, I did not understand why $U(0)$ is obviously $I$, i.e. $U(0) = I$. Why $U(0) = I$ ?

Comment: Does any evolution happen over zero seconds?

Comment: Related : [On the expression of evolution operator for a time-independent Hamiltonian in quantum mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/739373/).

Comment: The assumption is that at t=0 the object is fixed, that evolves with

Answer (score 2):

The evolution operator is an operator which expresses the wavefunction at time $t$ through the wavefunction at $t=0$:
\begin{equation}
|\psi(t)\rangle = U(t) |\psi(0)\rangle,
\end{equation}
this is Eq. (4.1) from "The Theoretical Minimum: Quantum Mechanics". At $t=0$, it should be
\begin{equation}
|\psi(0)\rangle = U(0) |\psi(0)\rangle
\end{equation}
for arbitrary initial wavefunction $|\psi(0)\rangle$. This can be true only for $U(0) = I$.